# MySQL - How to access all nodes in level 2 in table

Tags: php, database, categorization

I am creating a database for an e-commerce website which have nested categories and i am using **modified preorder traversal algo**. My question is how can i access all the nodes in level 2 i.e **Articles**, **Portfolio**, **Contact**

[image]

Comment: What are those numbers? Why that order?

Comment: @MihaiIorga http://imrannazar.com/Modified-Preorder-Tree-Traversal pls see this link

Comment: From my point of view, [this image](http://i.imgur.com/FP8pXTZ.png) should explain how I view a category tree structured. Much easier to select and get nodes. It would just be `SELECT * FROM categories where parent_id=1`

Comment: Read [this article](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Comment: @Todor i have read this, it didn't tell me how to get all the nodes in any particular level

Comment: The article *does* explain how to get the nodes in any particular level. See section `Find the Immediate Subordinates of a Node`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The article](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) does not explicitly tells you how to get all the nodes from one level. But if you read it carefully it tells you how to do more -> get the depth count of each category. Then all you have to do is to filter by that depth.

```
SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
FROM nested_category AS node, nested_category AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
GROUP BY node.name
HAVING depth = 1
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

**EDIT (what is going on):**

In order to make use of the `lft` and `rgt` columns of the `nested_category` table we should select the table twice.

```
SELECT *
FROM nested_category AS node, nested_category AS parent
```

if you inspect this query, you will find out that for each row in the `nested_category` we select all the rows again. So what we want now, is to remove all the rows from the first table (the one we called `AS node`) where they are not child's of their `parent`. That's why we filter with `WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt`

I want to mention that this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM nested_category AS node, nested_category AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

is equal to

```
SELECT *
FROM nested_category AS node
LEFT JOIN nested_category AS parent ON (node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt)
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

So now we have all child's with their parents + 1 (because of way we filter, every `child` belong to itself)

```
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+-------------+----------------------+------+------+
| category_id | name                 | lft | rgt | category_id | name                 | lft  | rgt  |
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+-------------+----------------------+------+------+
|           1 | ELECTRONICS          |   1 |  20 |           1 | ELECTRONICS          |    1 |   20 |
|           2 | TELEVISIONS          |   2 |   9 |           1 | ELECTRONICS          |    1 |   20 |
|           2 | TELEVISIONS          |   2 |   9 |           2 | TELEVISIONS          |    2 |    9 |
|           3 | TUBE                 |   3 |   4 |           1 | ELECTRONICS          |    1 |   20 |
|           3 | TUBE                 |   3 |   4 |           3 | TUBE                 |    3 |    4 |
|           3 | TUBE                 |   3 |   4 |           2 | TELEVISIONS          |    2 |    9 |
|           4 | LCD                  |   5 |   6 |           2 | TELEVISIONS          |    2 |    9 |
|           4 | LCD                  |   5 |   6 |           1 | ELECTRONICS          |    1 |   20 |
|           4 | LCD                  |   5 |   6 |           4 | LCD                  |    5 |    6 |
|           5 | PLASMA               |   7 |   8 |           1 | ELECTRONICS          |    1 |   20 |
|           5 | PLASMA               |   7 |   8 |           5 | PLASMA               |    7 |    8 |
|           5 | PLASMA               |   7 |   8 |           2 | TELEVISIONS          |    2 |    9 |
|           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |  10 |  19 |           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |   10 |   19 |
|           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |  10 |  19 |           1 | ELECTRONICS          |    1 |   20 |
|           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |  11 |  14 |           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |   11 |   14 |
|           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |  11 |  14 |           1 | ELECTRONICS          |    1 |   20 |
|           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |  11 |  14 |           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |   10 |   19 |
|           8 | FLASH                |  12 |  13 |           1 | ELECTRONICS          |    1 |   20 |
|           8 | FLASH                |  12 |  13 |           8 | FLASH                |   12 |   13 |
|           8 | FLASH                |  12 |  13 |           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |   10 |   19 |
|           8 | FLASH                |  12 |  13 |           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |   11 |   14 |
|           9 | CD PLAYERS           |  15 |  16 |           1 | ELECTRONICS          |    1 |   20 |
|           9 | CD PLAYERS           |  15 |  16 |           9 | CD PLAYERS           |   15 |   16 |
|           9 | CD PLAYERS           |  15 |  16 |           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |   10 |   19 |
|          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |  17 |  18 |           1 | ELECTRONICS          |    1 |   20 |
|          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |  17 |  18 |          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |   17 |   18 |
|          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |  17 |  18 |           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |   10 |   19 |
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+-------------+----------------------+------+------+
```

Next step - get the depth count. In order to do that, we have to group by every child (the example uses `GROUP BY node.name` but it can also be done on `node.category_id` and count the number of `parents` - 1 for each group `(COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth` (its also fine to use `parent.category_id` instead)

So doing

```
SELECT node.*, (COUNT(parent.category_id) - 1) AS depth
FROM nested_category AS node
LEFT JOIN nested_category AS parent ON (node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt)
GROUP BY node.category_id
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

we get this

```
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+-------+
| category_id | name                 | lft | rgt | depth |
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+-------+
|           1 | ELECTRONICS          |   1 |  20 |     0 |
|           2 | TELEVISIONS          |   2 |   9 |     1 |
|           3 | TUBE                 |   3 |   4 |     2 |
|           4 | LCD                  |   5 |   6 |     2 |
|           5 | PLASMA               |   7 |   8 |     2 |
|           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |  10 |  19 |     1 |
|           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |  11 |  14 |     2 |
|           8 | FLASH                |  12 |  13 |     3 |
|           9 | CD PLAYERS           |  15 |  16 |     2 |
|          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |  17 |  18 |     2 |
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+-------+
```

And now is the final step, to say that we want only these records, who have depth = 1 (`HAVING depth = 1`. `HAVING` is used here because it is applied after aggregates (and so it can filter on aggregates))

```
SELECT node.*, (COUNT(parent.category_id) - 1) AS depth
FROM nested_category AS node
LEFT JOIN nested_category AS parent ON (node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt)
GROUP BY node.category_id
HAVING depth = 1
ORDER BY node.lft;

+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+-------+
| category_id | name                 | lft | rgt | depth |
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+-------+
|           2 | TELEVISIONS          |   2 |   9 |     1 |
|           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |  10 |  19 |     1 |
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+-------+
```

I hope its more clear now. Again sorry for my bad English if i made some mistakes.

Comment: can u please explain what is going on ?

Comment: I will try, my writings skills in english are not very good, so I apologize if something is not well explained.

Comment: @Tudor can u tell me how to  reference these categories in my products table ?

Comment: What exactly do u mean ? If every product should have single category you could add `category_id` column on the products table. That way u could easy query all products in some category.

PS. and its Todor : )